# Control API requests using threshold percentage

Tags: java, spring, rest

I implemented chaos engineering framework in my project as below.

```
 - Created a new profile for chaos
 - Created Custom annotation
 - implemented method interceptor for the above custom annotation.
```

```
//Logic in MethodInterceptor 
// if chaos profile is enabled then call ExceptionAssault
// else proceed with regular flow.
```

The above is working as expected. Here I want to enhance this function to have additional control over triggering assaults as below

- using 2 additional configurable properties such as
  - requestLimit = 10 and ThresholdPercentage=50%
- enhance logic to: out of 10 requests randomly chose 5 requests and trigger the assault and other 5 requests should fall in else block i.e. proceeding with regular flow.

How to enhance the logic? TIA.

Comment: Are there any additional conditions for your requestLimit? Such as requestLimit per second

Comment: no additional conditions. Instead of requestLimit per second, i wanted to keep it simple like 50% requests per 10 requests. I checked the APIRateLimit library but they have it like requestLimit per second. So may be I can come up with a new algorithm to achieve something like this or if there is any lib already available i can use it. I couldnt find much on this though.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with below logic. I randomly select between True/False like below
`return new Random().nextBoolean();`
and increment counter for True(i.e. assault active). I kept a check on the counter. if the counter exceeds the threshold of 50% i.e 5 requests are true out of 10 then the rest 5 requests will not trigger the assault. I reset the counter after every 10 requests.